# Dividing a Python list into lists containing only unique values

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am building a scheduling tool, which has to make a schedule with the numbers 0-16. It must adhere to the following rules:

1. The schedule is size (10,7)
2. No one number may occur twice in a column
3. All numbers must occur the same amount of times (if the schedule
   size is not divisible by the numbers to choose from, some numbers
   can occur once more)

To make sure I can adhere to the third rule, I created a pool in which each number occurs with the same frequency, while the leftover is divided through random choice.

```
schedule = np.zeros((10,7))
IDs = [i for i in range(17)]

numberOfTasks = schedule.size

rounds = math.floor(numberOfTasks / len(IDs))
leftover = numberOfTasks % len(IDs)

pool = [person for person in IDs for _ in range(rounds)]
pool += random.sample(IDs, k=leftover)
```

This works, I now have a list of IDs of the same size as the schedule, all I need to do is put them in. Now, to adhere to the second rule, I should pick each number only once in each day/column. I tried this:

```
for i in range(schedule.shape[1]):
    
    daySchedule = schedule[:, i]
    plannablePeople = list(np.unique(pool))

    for j in range(len(daySchedule)):

        pickedPerson = random.choice(plannablePeople)
        plannablePeople.remove(pickedPerson)
        pool.remove(pickedPerson)
        daySchedule[j] = pickedPerson
    
    # Checking the scheduled day and the pool
    print(daySchedule)
    print(pool)

    schedule[:, i] = daySchedule
```

However, with this method I end up with an error in the last column because some ID's are left multiple times and therefore the plannablePeople list will be too short. Does anyone know if there is a more efficient way of solving this?

I thought there should be a way to split a list into lists with only unique items, but I yet have to find out how.

Comment: You will get a lot more help here if you add a code example the briefly shows what you are trying do rather than six paragraphs of text.

Comment: Thank you, I gave a try to simplify and create a simplified example of my code

Comment: Your edit is certainly an improvement, but I think a little more work will make it easier to answer. For example, what is the `self` in `self.pool`? Perhaps you could provide a MWE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , even including an example input (which does not have to be as big as 10x7 array)

Comment: I'm sorry, the self is because to keep my code as manageable as possible I used a class, stored the "pool" as an attribute. I am not sure how to create a MRE as there is nothing more to it than this code (I have no dataset or anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It sounds like you want to generate random samples from your `IDs`, without replacement, for each day in your schedule.***

To do this you can use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). You will see from the docs that it takes a keyword argument, `size`, which is the number of samples to take, and another keyword argument, `replace`, whose default value is `True`.

So something like:

```
numpy.random.choice(IDs, size=numberOfTasks, replace=False)
```

will generate one day's worth of scheduling for you.

A more complete, but simple example is as follows:

```
import numpy
import itertools

ndays = 7
njobs = 10
people = range(17)

days = [numpy.random.choice(people, size=njobs, replace=False) for d in range(ndays)]
schedule = numpy.array(days)
```

which gives the example `schedule`:

```
array([[11, 12, 14,  2,  0,  3, 10,  1,  6, 13],
       [ 8, 15,  7,  0, 12,  3,  1,  6, 10, 13],
       [ 2,  9, 16,  4,  5, 15,  0,  8,  7, 11],
       [ 1,  4, 10, 16,  6, 12,  2, 15, 13,  9],
       [ 8,  1,  7, 13, 12,  0,  3, 15,  4,  9],
       [ 2,  5,  7,  3,  9, 10, 13, 15,  0,  8],
       [ 7, 13, 14,  6,  8, 16,  3, 11,  1,  9]])
```

***A 'fair' schedule***

Your requirement for some sort of fairness is more difficult to enforce. I'm not totally convinced that your strategy of using a kind of worker pool works in general, though it may work reasonably well most of the time. Here is a short example which uses a pool. (Note that the extra work of finding the remainder `extra` and supplementing the pool with randomly sampled workers is not IMO necessary, since you'll be randomly sampling from the pool anyway)

```
import numpy
import itertools

ndays = 7
njobs = 10
people = [p for p in range(17)]
pool = people * ndays

schedule = numpy.zeros((7, 10), numpy.int)

for day in range(ndays):
    schedule[day, :] = numpy.random.choice(numpy.unique(pool), size=njobs, replace=False)
    for person in schedule[day, :]:
        pool.remove(person)
```

which gives the example `schedule`:

```
array([[12, 13,  0,  1,  2, 11,  6,  8, 16,  9],
       [15,  8,  3, 10,  5, 12,  7,  0, 11,  4],
       [12,  7, 13,  4,  0,  3, 15,  9, 14, 10],
       [14,  6, 16,  9,  4, 15, 11,  5, 10,  3],
       [ 0, 13,  6,  1, 12,  5, 15,  4,  7,  9],
       [13, 15, 16,  3,  5,  2,  8,  4,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3, 15,  5,  4, 10,  0,  8,  9,  1]])
```

(you can get a (10, 7) shape schedule with `schedule.T`)

With regard to your original example, the line `pool.remove(pickedPerson)` looks suspicious to me, and is more likely intended as `plannablePeople.remove(pickedPerson)`. There is also a small mistake elsewhere, such as the indexing in `daySchedule[i] = pickedPerson` which probably should be `daySchedule[j] = pickedPerson`. After correcting these, the example code in your question works well for me.

Notice also that your problem almost identical to the problem of generating Latin Squares (actually Latin Rectangle in your case, which you could obtain from any Latin Square large enough), although generating a single Latin Square is easy enough, random sampling uniformly (i.e. fairly) from all Latin Squares is so hard that it is NP-complete AFAIK. This hints (though its certainly not a proof) that it might be very hard to enforce the fairness requirements in your problem too.

Comment: I tried to elaborate more on why I used the "pool" in the original example. Basically, I want to schedule all numbers as evenly as possible. If I used random picking, some numbers are picked often while others are hardly occuring at all.

Comment: @MilanV take a look at the extended discussion in the edits for a hand wavy solution to these extended requirements

Comment: Thank you very much for the extended explanation, it allowed me to gain more insight in the problem itself. I guess all I can do now is find some non-optimal way to fill it anyway, or perhaps, drop a rule.